# Calling a printf with __VA_ARGS__ not working in a function but works in a macro

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-functions, variadic, variadic-macros

The following macro works:

```
#define DEBUG(msg, ...) printf(msg, __VA_ARGS__)
```

But when I add my own function, it says `error: '__VA_ARGS__' was not declared in this scope`.
My code:

```
void Debug(const char* msg, ...) {
    printf(msg, __VA_ARGS__);
}

#define DEBUG(msg, ...) Debug(msg, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` is a variadic macro *only* thing. There are plenty of tutorials and examples for variadic functions online if you want to make one.

Answer (score 2):

Variadic parameter pack is your friend in this case:

```cpp
template< typename ... Args >
void Debug( const char * msg, Args ... args ) {
    printf( msg, args ... );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`__VA_ARGS__` simply does not exist outside of a variadic macro. For what you are attempting, use [`vprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead of `printf()`, eg:

```c
void Debug(const char* msg, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vprintf(msg, args);
    va_end(args);
}

#define DEBUG(msg, ...) Debug(msg, __VA_ARGS__)
```